# Why does Git store submodule URLs in two places?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-config

While updating Git submodule paths when we switched hosts at work, I was surprised to find that the paths are stored in .gitmodules and in the .git/config file.

What is the thinking/reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.gitmodules` file is shipped with the repository and specifies the location to use when cloning the repository fresh.  However, `.git/config` is used to store the values you wish to use for the given instance.

This approach is helpful when you wish to use a different URL than the one specified in the config.  For example, you may have an internal mirror of the submodule, or you may wish to use SSH instead of HTTPS.  It also means that the contents of the repository are not needed except during initial clone, so you need not worry about a `git pull` or `git checkout` from an untrusted fork modifying your configuration and merge conflicts on `.gitmodules` don't impact submodule operations.

Additionally, Git's security model doesn't permit untrusted configuration files: someone who can modify your repository's configuration can execute arbitrary code.  By copying only specific configuration settings and only once, Git can avoid having to have special code to read only sanitized entries out of the working tree.

If you want to sync them, you can use `git submodule sync` to do so.